# how to find difference between current time and particular time of day in java

Tags: java, datetime

I want to find out difference in milliseconds between next occuring 3PM new york time and current time. i.e. if it is 5 pm NY time right now. I should get the difference between 5pm now and 3pm NY time next day. How can I do it in Java ? I am happy using JodaTime also, may you please give an exmaple, how this can be done.

Please help.

Comment: Send your codes, tell where to stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three solutions using the most prevalent library choices. They all follow the same pattern, just using the nomenclature of the given libraries.

### Joda solution:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("US/Eastern"));
DateTime target = dt
    .withHourOfDay(15)
    .withMinuteOfHour(0)
    .withSecondOfMinute(0)
    .withMillisOfSecond(0);

if (target.isBefore(dt)) {
  target = target.plusDays(1);
}

System.out.println(target.getMillis() - dt.getMillis());
```

### Java 8 solution

*Got to love that `until()` method:*

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
ZonedDateTime target2 = zdt
    .withHour(15)
    .withMinute(0)
    .withSecond(0)
    .withNano(0);

if (target2.isBefore(zdt)) {
  zdt = zdt.plusDays(1);
}

System.out.println(zdt.until(target2, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
```

### Java <=7 solution

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
Calendar target3 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
target3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
target3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
target3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
target3.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if (target3.before(c)) {
  target3.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

System.out.println(target3.getTimeInMillis() - c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't wanted to complicate it too much. But this program can run any time and it actually needs to run on London server and compare with NY 3pm time. How do I make sure I get correct results even when this program runs at 1:00 am LDN time.

Comment: @user835791 I made an edit to the Java 8 solution. I think this will now work whenever and wherever it is called from. If you think otherwise, can you describe a problem with it? The final comparison is essentially made using epoch values, so the timezones are ignored there.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
    Date now = new Date();
    Calendar ny3pmCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    ny3pmCalendar.setTime(now);
    if(ny3pmCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 15) {
        // next day
        ny3pmCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }
    ny3pmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 15);
    ny3pmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    ny3pmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    ny3pmCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    long diff = ny3pmCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTime();
    System.out.println(diff);
```

Comment: This will fail if the time is already exactly 3pm in NYC. Your first if statement will trigger and you'll compare with 3pm the next day. You have to test to see if it's exactly 3pm already, or adopt a pattern similar to my answer.

Comment: @KumarAbhinav Not 100% :-)

Comment: @KumarAbhinav It isn't generally considered good etiquette to edit code in other people's answer. Comments (and possibly down-voting) is the way to point out errors.

Comment: @robert Even though it's broken?

Comment: In principle it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

try joda DateTime and Period

```
    Date oldDate = new Date();
    DateTime old = new DateTime(oldDate);
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    Period period = new Period(old, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
    period.getYears();// give the difference in year
    period.getMonths();
    period.getDays();
    period.getMinutes();
    period.getSeconds();
```

[Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) - Its having lots of features for date time manipulation